# Mongodb constantly ending connections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, digital-ocean

We have a Mongodb instance running on DigitalOcean. We use Nodejs to connect four clients to this database, all configured with the same parameters:

```
MongoClient.connect({
        // maxPoolSize: 200, // default is 100
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    },
```

In the db logs, we see lines like this several times per second:

```
component: "NETWORK"
message: "Connection ended"
context: "conn4090969"
attr: {
  remote: "127.0.0.1:41496",
  connectionId: 4090969,
  connectionCount: 289
}
```

and

```
component : "ACCESS"
message : "Authentication succeeded"
context : "conn4090966"
attr : {
    mechanism : "SCRAM-SHA-1"
    speculative : false
    principalName : "mms-automation"
    authenticationDatabase : "admin"
    remote : "127.0.0.1:41484"
    extraInfo : {}
}
```

db.serverStatus().connections shows:

```
active: 60
available: 50911
awaitingTopologyChanges: 1336093
current: 289
exhaustHello: 28
exhaustMaster: 14
totalCreated: 4093263
```

Why are so many connections being created and dropped all the time?

Comment: Where are those connections coming from?   Perhaps DigitalOcean has some processes that routinely connect to check the health of the database server?

Comment: Have you whitelisted the IPs from where you are trying to connect to your MongoDB instance?